# ketcher iframe renders to fullpage with express serve static

Tags: node.js, express, iframe

I have installed node js v18.16.0
My OS: is Win10
My Device: Asus Zenbook 3
Browser: Chrome Version 113.0.5672.127

I downloaded ketcher 2.9.0 as standalone (https://lifescience.opensource.epam.com/ketcher/index.html) and added it in my .html-file via iframe. Now when I visit the localhost page served by node js express, the ketcher molecular editor brakes out of the iframe and doesn't stay in my own page.

With the following .html:

```
<title></title>
<form name="search">
  <select>
    <option>CAS</option>
    <option>Supplier</option>
    <option>Substance</option>
    <option>Reaction</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="search">
</form>

<!-- <a href="standalone/index.html">Ketcher</a> -->
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts" id="ifKetcher" src="standalone/index.html" width="800px" height="600px"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

My node-code looks like:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const index = fs.readFileSync('web.html', 'utf-8');
app.use(express.static('standalone'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send(index.toString());
});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(Example app listening on port ${port});
});
```

Now when I run node index.js and call via chrome localhost, Chrome shows me the ketcher application over the whole page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC2uq.png)

I instead want to stay in my page and see the html-formular in my webpage and the ketcher molecular editor inside the iframe.

I wouldd be happy for a Feedback!

Thanks in advance!

Jornelson